# Login loop after unpacking .tar files in home directory

Tags: login, citrix

I tried to install citrix receiver on Ubuntu 18.04, but accidentally unpacked the .tar files in home directory. I could not remove the files. After rebooting I am stuck in a login loop.
I'm working on a Vostro 5590 Dell laptop with a 5.3.0-28-generic kernel (downgraded from 5.3.0-40 a few days ago). 
How do I get out of the loop?

EDIT: I deleted the unpacked files and .tar.gz files with sudo rm via text login, but now I think maybe I should have done this differently, since I'm still in login loop after rebooting. I still see Maintainer scripts in the home directory, though I'm not sure if they belong to the files I tried to install.

Comment: If there is insufficient space in $HOME at login for creation of required GUI work files, the login cannot proceed and you are logged out (no messages), ie. login loop is the effect.  Text logins will still work allowing you to fix the *out-of-space* problem.

Comment: I deleted the files using text login now, but still looping after reboot..

Comment: It would be helpful to know the exact command(s) you used (ex. `history | tail`) - I wonder if perhaps you managed to change the ownership or permissions of your user's home directory?

Comment: Only "sudo rm" a bunch of files, including the "conffiles" and the .tar.gz files. I did check those permissions first thing (following one solution I found online) and everything seemed to be in order. I used `chown username:username .Xauthority` and the like to check.